# How to call one fragment from another activity without using begin transaction?

Tags: java, android, android-activity, fragment

I used this code below from one adapter class-

```
AuthorDetailsFragment fragment = new AuthorDetailsFragment();
                Bundle b = new Bundle();
                b.putString("authorId", "" + modelAllAuthors.get(pos).getId());

                fragment.setArguments(b);
                ((HomeActivity) context).addFragment(fragment, true);
```

This code works well. But when I am trying to call the fragment from another activity using same process it is not working. So, can I call the mentioned fragment from another activity?

Comment: Definitely, you are not in `HomeActivity`. so it cant call `addFragment`

Comment: Is there any way to call that fragment from my current activity?

Comment: Of course, you can call any fragment from any activity. That's why fragments are helpful in Android.

Comment: It will be very nice if you provide me one example to understand it properly in that case @salman

Comment: I meant what you wrote in your `addFragment` method.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the following piece of code whenever you want to add a fragment.

```
   private void addFragment(@IdRes int containerViewId,
                           @NonNull Fragment fragment,
                           @NonNull String fragmentTag) {

    getSupportFragmentManager()
            .beginTransaction()
            .add(containerViewId, fragment, fragmentTag)
            .commit();
}
```

Comment: can you please have a look to the question I have asked in the following link-
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53616758/how-can-we-call-one-fragment-from-another-class-that-doesnt-contain-that-fragme/53616870?noredirect=1#comment94095574_53616870

Comment: The id of your container of the fragment like `R.id.container`

Comment: yes, I called it inside one onClick event inside my adapter class-


getSupportFragmentManager()
                        .beginTransaction()
                        .add(R.id.container_idea, fragment, "Ideas")
                        .commit();

But it is not getting the getSupportFragmentManager() method