# How can we call one fragment from another class that doesn't contain that fragment?

Tags: java, android, android-activity, fragment, adapter

I am having one activity class : **IdeaBoxActivity** 
Here is the layout code of the activity-

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context="com.asif047">


    <android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:id="@+id/dl"
        >

        <LinearLayout
            android:id="@+id/flcontent"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:orientation="vertical">

            <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
                android:id="@+id/toolbar_idea_box"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:background="?attr/colorPrimary"
                android:minHeight="?attr/actionBarSize"
                app:contentInsetLeft="0dp"
                app:contentInsetStart="16dp"
                app:popupTheme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Light"
                app:theme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Dark.ActionBar" />



            <android.support.design.widget.TabLayout
                android:id="@+id/tabs_idea"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:background="?attr/colorPrimary"
                app:tabTextColor="#ffffff"
                />


        <android.support.v4.view.ViewPager
            android:id="@+id/container_idea"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior" />



        </LinearLayout>

        <android.support.design.widget.NavigationView

            android:id="@+id/nv"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_gravity="start"
            android:background="#ffffff"
            app:headerLayout="@layout/header"
            app:itemIconTint="#000000"
            app:itemTextColor="#000000"
            app:menu="@menu/drawermenu"

            >


        </android.support.design.widget.NavigationView>


    </android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout>



</android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout>
```

I have added some fragments in the **IdeaBoxActivity** .

I have added the fragments using following method-

```
private void setupViewPager(ViewPager viewPager) {
    SectionPageadapter sectionPageadapter = new SectionPageadapter(getSupportFragmentManager());
    sectionPageadapter.addFragment(new IdeasFragment(), "Ideas");
    sectionPageadapter.addFragment(new WriteIdeaFragment(), "Write Idea");
    sectionPageadapter.addFragment(new MyIdeasFragment(), "My Ideas");

    viewPager.setAdapter(sectionPageadapter);
}
```

Among these fragments one is : **IdeasFragment**

I have another activity which named:  **HappyWallActivity**
From this Activity  I have called one adapter class named:  **RecyclerAdapterSeeAll**

```
public class RecyclerAdapterSeeAll extends RecyclerView.Adapter<RecyclerAdapterSeeAll.MyViewHolder>{

    private List<ModelHappySeeAll> modelHappySeeAlls;
    private Context context;
    private int id = 0;
    private String status = "";

    public RecyclerAdapterSeeAll( Context context, List<ModelHappySeeAll> modelHappySeeAlls) {
        this.modelHappySeeAlls = modelHappySeeAlls;
        this.context = context;
    }


    @Override
    public MyViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
        View view = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext()).inflate(R.layout.row_item_see_all, parent, false);
        return  new MyViewHolder(view);
    }

    @Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(MyViewHolder holder, int position) {

        holder.tvName.setText(modelHappySeeAlls.get(position).getName());
        holder.tvDetails.setText(modelHappySeeAlls.get(position).getDetails());

        holder.setItemClickListener(new ItemClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onItemClick(int pos) {


            }
        });



    }

    @Override
    public int getItemCount() {
        return modelHappySeeAlls.size();
    }


    public class MyViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder implements View.OnClickListener{
        TextView tvName, tvDetails;
        ItemClickListener itemClickListener;

        public MyViewHolder(View itemView) {
            super(itemView);
            tvName = itemView.findViewById(R.id.textview_name_see_all);
            tvDetails = itemView.findViewById(R.id.textview_happy_post_see_all);
        }

        public void setItemClickListener ( ItemClickListener itemClickListener){
            this.itemClickListener = itemClickListener;
            itemView.setOnClickListener(this);
        }

        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            this.itemClickListener.onItemClick(this.getLayoutPosition());
        }
    }

}
```

In this class inside **holder.setItemClickListener** I want to call **IdeasFragment** of the **IdeaBoxActivity**.

Is there any way of doing this? If yes, then please help me with the code that should work.

Answer (score 0):

You have to use the same instance of Ideas fragment by probably storing the original instance made on `new IdeasFragment()` to a global variable, or you could pass the instance when you do `new RecyclerAdapterSeeAll(IdeasFragment instance)` and use it like that. Either way the idea here is to use the same instances on both classes.

[Globals in java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4646577/global-variables-in-java)

```
public static IdeasFragment myInstance= new IdeasFragment(); 

private void setupViewPager(ViewPager viewPager) {
    SectionPageadapter sectionPageadapter = new 
    SectionPageadapter(getSupportFragmentManager());
    sectionPageadapter.addFragment(myInstance, "My Ideas");

    viewPager.setAdapter(sectionPageadapter);
}
```

And on the click listener:

```
public void setItemClickListener ( ItemClickListener itemClickListener){

    IdeaBoxActivity.myInstance.start(); // call the function needed to start the IdeasFragment here
}
```

Comment: Sorry I am not getting it properly, can you please help me out with the code that I should write inside the onItemClick method?

Comment: What do you want to do inside setItemClickListener with ideaboxactivity?

Comment: To Call it's function you need to do IdeaBoxActivity.myInstance.functionName(params). Did that help?

Comment: from setItemClickListener I just want to start my IdeasFragment

Comment: Note that you should not instantiate IdeaBoxActivity as `new IdeaBoxActivity()` to be able to use the myInstance variable. It's a static variable, meaning a reference to the base class is not needed to use it else where. Although, you may have to import the class but that's about it.

Comment: I have edited my question, can you please refer to it?

Comment: Sorry, still not solving my problem

Comment: I have created the instance of IdeaFragment inside the IdeaBoxActivity and inside the onClick method -------

 SectionPageadapter sectionPageadapter = new
                        SectionPageadapter(getSupportFragmentManager());
                sectionPageadapter.addFragment(IdeaBoxActivity.ideasFragment, "My Ideas");

                viewPager.setAdapter(sectionPageadapter);

-----------------------
I wrote the above code. but it is not getting the getSupportFragmentManager() method and viewPager as well